# Add double quote only to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have values from a for loop which i create an object using them.

my final object comes with single and double quotes. i only want it to get with double quote around the key.

i have tried to use

```
  a.value = `${arrayString[i]}`;
  a.value = arrayString[i] + '';
  a.value = arrayString[i]; 
  a.value = arrayString[i].toString(); 
  a.value = String(arrayString[i]);
```

a.value is my key. 
when i use :  `a.value = JSON.stringify(arrayString[i]);`

and then i `console.log(a.value) // "a"`
i get the key how i want it but when i try to add it to my final object i get it with an extra single quote around it :

`{ '"a"': 2, '"b"': 2, '"c"': 1, '"aa"': 3 } //what i get on my console.log`

`{"a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 1, "aa": 3} // what i expect what i get on my console.log`

this is how i push to my final object `a.count = myCount;
      finalResultObject[a.value] = a.count;`

`myCount` is only a generated number i get in my loop

Edit**

this is a function which count the number of words in a specific string

```
exports.countWordsInString = (someString) => {
  let arrayString = [];
  arrayString = someString.split(' ');
  arrayString = arrayString.filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0);
  var finalResultObject = {};

  // make a copy of the input array
  var copy = arrayString.slice(0);

  // first loop goes over every element
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++) {

    var myCount = 0;
    // loop over every element in the copy and see if it's the same
    for (var w = 0; w < copy.length; w++) {
      if (arrayString[i] === copy[w]) {
        // increase amount of times duplicate is found
        myCount++;
        // sets item to undefined
        delete copy[w];
      }
    }

    if (myCount > 0) {
      var a = {};
      // a.value =   '" \\' + arrayString[i] + '"'
      // a.value = `${arrayString[i]}`;
      // a.value = arrayString[i] + '';
      // a.value = arrayString[i];
      // a.value = arrayString[i].toString();
      a.value = JSON.stringify(arrayString[i]);

      console.log(a.value)
      a.count = myCount;
      finalResultObject[a.value] = a.count;

    }
  }
  // finalResultObject.replace(/\'/gi,'')
  console.log(finalResultObject);

  return finalResultObject;
};
```

about this function and how it works : it gets a string and make a copy of it then we do two for loops original and copy then on some condition i add count and increase it by one then i delete the count for the coming copy item

and this is a unite test for it using jest for more calcification :

```
test('output number of words in string', () => {
  const text = countWordsInString('a b a c aa aa aa    b');
  expect(text).toBe({"a": 2, "b": 2, "c": 1, "aa": 3})
});
```

this shows in my console when i use `a.value = JSON.stringify(arrayString[i]);`

[image: this shows in my console when i use <code>a.value = JSON.stringify(arrayString[i]);</code>]

this shows in my console when i use `a.value = arrayString[i];`
[image]

Comment: When you say "this is what I get", you mean this is what you see in console.log?

Comment: Maybe you should show the actual code in full.

Comment: If `arrayString[i]` are already strings, then there is no need to use `JSON.stringify()` as it will just wrap your strings in quotes

Comment: `a.value = arrayString[i];` should've worked. Why do you think it doesn't ?

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. You are comparing apples with oranges.